# Why is my answer wrong for this inequality $\frac{\left(1-x\right)}{x^2+x}<0$

Tags: inequality

Good evening to everyone. So I have this inequality: $$\frac{\left(1-x\right)}{x^2+x} <0 $$ It becomes $$ \frac{\left(1-x\right)}{x^2+x} <0 \rightarrow \left(1-x\right)\left(x^2+x\right)<0 \rightarrow x^3-x>0 \rightarrow x\left(x^2-1\right)>0 $$ Therefore from the first $ x>0 $, from the second $ x_1 = 1 $ and $x_2=-1$ therefore $ x $ belongs to $(-\infty,-1)$ and $(1,\infty)$ therefore $x$ belongs to $(1,\infty)$. But on the answer sheet it shows that it's defined on $(-1,0)$ and $(1,\infty)$. Where I am wrong? Thanks for any response.

Comment: Since the comparison is with $0$, you should do a sign-change graph and see what happens to the numerator and denominator...

Comment: @abiessu thanks I think that I'll try that

Comment: You are wrong let me add a solution

Comment: You _cannot_ multiply by $x^2+x$ without assuming $x^2+x >0$ without changing the inequality.  You are approaching this in a most incorrect way!

Comment: Multiplication with $(x^2+x)^2$ is fine.

Comment: I can only understand a *single* thing you did *anywhere* in this solution.  You start with $(1-x)/(x^2 - x) < 0 \implies (1-x)(x^2 - x) < 0$.  Why on earth would that be true?  Then you get $(1-x)(x^2 - x) < 0 \implies x^3 - x > 0$.  Why on earth would you assume that.  Then you concluded $x(x^2 - 1) > 0$.  This is the only thing I understand and agree with.  Then you conclude $x > 0$.  This is absolutely wrong but I understand why you said it.  Consider $(-5)(-4) > 0 \not \implies -5 > 0$.

Comment: @fleablood I started with $\frac{\left(1-x\right)}{x^2-x}<0$ if you multiply by $\left(x^2-x\right)^2 $ and then simplify you'll get $ \left(1-x\right)\left(x^2-x\right) $. So the first expression is good. Then the final result is $x-x^3<0$ if you change the sign it becomes the reverse(the exact expression you were asking for. With $ x>0 $ I know it's a mistake that I have to treat more carefully in the future.

Comment: @fleablood $\frac{a}{b}<0$ iff $ab<0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you write this $\frac{1 - x}{x(1 + x)} < 0$ you will find that the critical point are at $x = \{-1, 0, 1\}$.  You can simply plug in $x = -2$ to find that:

$$
\frac{1 + 2}{4 - 2} = \frac{3}{2} > 0
$$

Therefore this expression is $> 0$ when $x < -1$, $< 0$ when $-1 < x < 0$,it's $>0$ when $0 < x < 1$ and it's $<0$ when $x > 1$.

Therefore this is true when:

$$
(-1, 0) \wedge (1, \infty)
$$

**Comment:**

Take a long hard look at my anser.  It's compact but it's concise if you take enough to look at it.  My answer relies on the fact that a sign change requires an "odd" factor (all of your factors are odd).  As soon as you establish the sign of *any* region you have established the sign of *all* regions!

**A more "Rigorous" Way:**

A more rigorous way is to show where each of the factors are positive or negative.  The following picture shows the three factors and their sign chart when $x = -1$, $x = 0$, and $x = 1$ (the three vertical lines).

\begin{align}
1-  x > 0 \rightarrow x < 1 \\
x > 0 \rightarrow x > 0\\
1 + x > 0 \rightarrow x > -1
\end{align}

This shows a sign chart where we have:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are only considering two roots for the cubic polynomial. The polynomial has three roots, $-1,0,1$ and they are all simple root.

Hence the polynomials is positive on $(1,\infty)$. (it is positive as it goes to positive infinity).

The sign changes at the roots.

it is negative on $(0,1)$. positive on $(-1,0)$, negative on $(-\infty,-1)$.

Comment: What about when $x > 1$, clearly this inequality is negative???

Comment: I am working with $x(x^2-1)>0$ rather than the initial inequality (of which the opposite works)

Comment: I don't understand your comment of $x(x^2+2)^2$...it doesn't work because your inequality if wrong for the initial statement of $\frac{1-x}{x^2+x} < 0$ which is only true for $x\in (-1,0)\cup (1, \infty)$.

Comment: $$\frac{1-x}{x^2+x}<0$$ 
if and only if
$$\frac{1-x}{x^2+x}(x^2+x)^2<0$$ 
if and only if 
$$(1-x)(x^2+x)<0$$
if and only if 
$$x(x^2-1)>0$$

Comment: "Another" way to understand is $\frac{a}{b}<0$ iff $ab<0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = x(x^2-1)= x^3-x$$
$$f'(x)= 3x^2-1$$ then x get local extreme value at point x =  $\sqrt 3 /3   $or $-\sqrt 3 /3 $

And it is on the interval ($-\infty$,$-\sqrt 3 /3  $) or ($\sqrt 3 /3   $,$+\infty$) is increasing and the interval  ($-\sqrt 3 /3  $,$\sqrt 3 /3$) is decreasing.

$$f(-\sqrt 3 /3) \geq0$$
$$f(\sqrt 3 /3) \leq 0$$

So it can draw the $f(x)$'s diagram:

[image: The image of function f(x)]
EDIT: your answer is wrong because x>0 is not necessary. For instance, x = -0.5, x<0, however $x^2-1 <0$ rather than bigger than 1. Therefore you can't assert x>0.

Answer (score 0):

In inequality questions, first you need to make all the coefficients of $x$ positive.

We can write it as
$$\frac{x-1}{x(x+1)}>0$$

Now , multiply both sides by $(x(x+1))^2$ which is always greater than $0$.
Hence we are left with this 
$$x(x-1)(x+1)>0$$

Solving this critical points are at $x=-1,0,1$
Plot a number line mark these points. Now on the extreme right hand side interval mark $+$ , and then going fro right to left.. mark alternating $-$ then $+$ .. and so on..

Now see the $+$ intervals on the number line which is marked in the interval
$$ x \in (-1,0) \cup (1,\infty)$$

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is ok up to $x(x^2-1)>0.$ The next sentence is unintelligible ("from the first $x>0$".  First what? And what are $x_1, x_2$?).

Observe that $x(x^2-1)>0\iff x^3>x $ $\iff [(x>0\land x^2>1)\lor (x<0\land x^2<1)\lor (x=0\land PigsCanFly)]$ $\iff (x>1\lor -1<x<0).$

And if you  wrote any 1-way implications, you now have to now check whether $(x>1\lor -1<x<0)\implies (1-x)/(x^2+x)<0.$ You can avoid the need for this check by writing  $$(1-x)/(x^2+x)<0\iff ((1-x)(x^2+x)<0 \iff x^3>x\iff x\in \{-1,0\}\cup \{1,\infty)$$ and with the additional steps, between " $x^3>x$" and the last formula, preceded and followed  by valid " $\iff$ ".